# How to deal with a time series with multiple points at each time (in R)?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have a time series with a few different observations at each time step (measurements of the same phenomenon, but from different locations) and it looks like it might have a weak cyclical pattern, but I'm not sure. How would I implement the acf function in R to get a better idea of what's going on? Can I call it on the whole time series as is? Do I need to separate the time series by location so that there is just one observation at each date? Do I need to fit a model first and look at the residuals?

Comment: Why not model the locations, too? 'nlme::lme' does provide facilities to model an ARMA correlation structure in a mixed effects model.

Comment: Great suggestion, I had not considered that. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a neat trick for solving this issue. I divided the data by location, and then concatenated them as one long time series. The problem with this though is that I don't want to take into account the lag from the end of one series to the beginning of the next, so I inserted a bunch of NAs in between the series and used the argument na.action=na.pass and set lag.max to the number of NAs I inserted. In this case my data spanned a year with one observation every two weeks (26 time increments long), so I inserted 26 NAs between each series.

```
new.time.series<- c(Loc1Series, rep(NA,26), Loc2Series, rep(NA,26), Loc3Series,     rep(NA,26))
acf(new.time.series, na.action=na.pass, lag.max=30)
```

This allowed me to utilize all of my data to find a pattern, whereas if I had tried this analysis one location at a time I would have found little of significance due to sparse data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to store them.  I generally live and die by [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) and [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) and they (strongly) prefer distinct and (strictly) monotonically increasing index values -- aka timestamps for xts.

So in one case where I "relatively few" collisions relative to the data size, and with the smallest increment "still small" to the median increment, I fudged by making the time stamps unique.  In fact, I did that so often and mailed so frequently with the authors that xts ended up with `make.time.unique()` ...

Comment: My data occur in nice, neat time steps (every 2 weeks for a year), but I have 5 observations from each date, all measurements taken from different locations. Should I just average these and treat them as one time series? Or look at them individually by location? I thought I might be losing some information by looking at them individually by location because I have relatively little data at a time if I divide it up that way.

Comment: Hard to say -- either you make them separate (but "sparse") or you keep them (but loose information, and need to "fudge").  But hey, you are the subject matter expert so we let you decide :)